# Excel VBA - Loop to check entire column range rather than each cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a script which checks a range of cells in column range 4 (Column D) for non-blank values, if it finds a non blank value, it copies that value and pastes it to a cell in column range 6 (Column F).  The script runs, but it is awfully slow, the script takes 5 minutes to process and complete its run.  Is there any way to improve this script so that it can pre-check the range  before it copies and pastes the values across?  It seems that the copy / paste function is slowing it down.

Code below

```
Sub ArrayCopyPaste()
Dim J as Integer
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For J = 2 To 500
    If Cells(J, 4).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(J, 4).Copy
        Cells(J, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next J

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you sort? What about using formula? I mean, if what you want done is that simple a simple `IF formula` can do that. Why VBA?

Comment: There is more code that goes through the list, finds blanks, and deletes them (effectively creating a consolidated list).  You can use formulas to do this but it is incredibly taxing on memory (The sheet used to have an array formula, but the if loops do it far more effectively)

Comment: Ok, I posted something. That process your example in less than a sec.

Comment: Why bother checking for blanks before copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r1, r2, n As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> change to suit
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        r1 = Application.Transpose(.Range("D2:D" & lrow))
        r2 = Application.Transpose(.Range("F2:F" & lrow))
        For n = LBound(r1) To UBound(r1)
            If r1(n) <> "" Then r2(n) = r1(n)
        Next
        .Range("F2:F" & lrow) = Application.Transpose(r2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Transfer range data to array, then do the comparison process array to array.
Then return the array to range. HTH.

**Important:** *Application.Transpose* have limitation. I can handle only a few thousand data.

**Follow up:** Try this for deleting

```
Dim rngToDelete As Range, k As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> change to suit
    For k = 2 To 500
        If .Cells(k, 6).Value = "" Then
            If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDelete = .Cells(k, 6)
            Else
                Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, .Cells(k, 6))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rngToDelete.Delete xlUp
    'rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete xlUp ~~> use this if you want to delete entire row.
End With
```

Determine all the target range first then delete in one go. HTH.

Comment: That did it! it runs much faster now, I think the only thing that chews up time now is the line to get rid of all the blank cells, see below.  Can you suggest anything to build this into the transpose range?

For K = 2 To 500
    If Cells(K, 6).Value = "" Then
    Cells(K, 6).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
Next K

Comment: @PootyToot You wanna try what I posted in follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply doing this first and see if it makes a difference:

```
Dim currentCalculation As Variant
currentCalculation = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For J = 2 To 500
    If Cells(J, 4).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(J, 4).Copy
        Cells(J, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next J

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Calculation = currentCalculation
```

---

Another thought. Have you tried just doing this?

```
For J = 2 To 500
    If Cells(J, 4).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(J, 6).Value = Cells(J, 4).Value
    End If
Next J
```

Comment: I should have added, the code already has calculation set to Manual but it is set in an earlier sub

Comment: @PootyToot - What about screen updating?

Comment: Screen Updating is also set to false until the end of the code, i am trying your variant now to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

It won't make any difference to your target column if the blanks are copied, so don't bother checking for them. **Don't loop -- just copy the entire column.**

```
Sub CopyColumn()
    ' copying this way does not use your clipboard
    Columns("D").Copy Columns("F")
End Sub
```

If you only need a portion of the column, specify the range to copy rather than the entire column:

```
Sub CopyPartOfColumn()
    ' copying this way does not use your clipboard
    Range("D2:D500").Copy Range("F2:F500")
End Sub
```

You mention in a comment below your question that you want the resulting column to be a consolidated list of the values without the blanks. You can quickly do that by deleting the blanks from the column or range, once again without looping. Run this after you've copied the values you want.

```
Sub RemoveBlanks()
    Range("F2:F500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```